# parse date from sqlserver to c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I need some guidance for parsing dates. My database table contains values
ID (int) and date (datetime: yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff format) and status 
example

```
1000 & 2014-02-18 20:32:20.657 & 1
2000 & 2014-02-18 20:32:20.658 & 1
3000 & NULL                    & -1
```

I have a C# program that looks at this table for status=1 and date not null and want to insert ID and Date in the same format in a text file. 
The text file should have

```
1000    2014-02-18 20:32:20.657
2000    2014-02-18 20:32:20.658
```

Here's the code.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdSel = new SqlCommand(sqlSelNew, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmdSel.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader1.Read())
    {
      DataSet ds = GetData(sqlSelNew);
      CultureInfo _provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
       ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader1["ID"].ToString());
       string dtformat = @"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
       var d = DateTime.ParseExact(dateresized,dtformat , _provider);
       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(txtfilepath, true))
        {
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.WriteLine(ID + "   " + d);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
```

I get "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." error. How can I handle this?
Thanks
Rashmi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you shouldn't have to parse the date. You should simply be able to use `reader.GetDateTime()` to read that column and assign it.  Second, why are you both filling up a `DataSet` and using a `SqlDataReader` to get the values directly?  I'd expect one or the other but not both.  Third, you ought to be wrapping your reader in a `using` statement as it implements `IDisposable`.

```
using (var reader1 = cmdSel.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader1.Read())
    {
       var id = reader1.GetInt32(0);
       var date = reader1.GetDateTime(1);

       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the changes above. txt file has date in different format i.e. 1000   2/18/2014 9:04:06 PM instead of 2014-02-11 21:04:06.770

Comment: @Rashmi - you need to use a format on the data output, not in parsing the input, to specify what you want, e.g., `sw.WriteLine("{0} {1:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", id, date);`